# I have Netherlands residence permit and an Indian passport. Can I visit Bulgaria?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, bulgaria

I live in the Netherlands with a valid residence permit. I hold an Indian passport.

For visiting Bulgaria for leisure for three days do I need a visa?

I have already booked the tickets.

Comment: I believe that as a short-term visitor your residence permit exempts you from a visa, but I don't have time to confirm that at the moment.  I imagine someone will correct me if I am wrong in fairly short order.

Answer (score 3):

No, you don't need visa for a short-term visit to Bulgaria with Netherlands residence permit. According to Timatic:

> The following are exempt from holding a visa:
>
> Passengers with a residence permit issued by Netherlands for a maximum
>   stay of 90 days.
>
> The maximum stay is granted within 180 days.
>
> Passengers with a D visa issued by Netherlands for a maximum stay of
>   90 days.
>
> The maximum stay is granted within 180 days.
>
> Additional information:
>
> Visitors are required to hold proof of sufficient funds to cover their
>   stay and documents required for their next destination.

However it is suggested to check the visa requirements before booking tickets, unless they're refundable, as the airline will not refund you on the grounds of not having a visa.

Comment: Is there a website where from you can know this by yourself for any country/passport/visa etc. ?

Comment: **The maximum stay is granted within 180 days.** - within 180 days of what ?

Comment: @Imran This just means that you can stay for up to 90 days in a period of 180 days. So you cannot stay 90 days, leave the country for one day and come back for another 90 days. Same rule applies to regular short stay Schengen visa.

Comment: What's the source for the quote?

Comment: This is from Timatic

Answer (score 2):

Although not in the Schengen area, Bulgaria would like to be, and as part of their application process is applying Schengen rules as though already a signatory to the Schengen agreement. Since about 99% of the rules that are of general interest are applied in the same way by every Schengen member it is fairly safe to assume that whatever of a routine nature is the case for a Schengen country, for example the types of visas and in particular the [90-180-visa-rules](/questions/tagged/90-180-visa-rules) (see Usage guide) and the [Short-stay Visa Calculator](http://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/content/visa-calculator_en) (for [details](https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/sites/homeaffairs/files/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/border-crossing/docs/short_stay_schengen_calculator_user_manual_en.pdf)), is applicable.